# how to use bash to add a string to each named hosts file

Tags: linux, bash

I need to add a record to several hosts file in Linux named directory with a bash script.
I want to open each hosts file and add the line:

```
webmail.domain.com. IN A 192.168.1.1
```

for each domain.com.hosts file in the named directory. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: thanks the problem is that each file has different "domain.com" so the script should add the string based on domain.com.hosts file

Comment: show some of the file names

Comment: code this is file domain.com.hosts  
domain.com. IN SOA ns1.domain.com. root.domain.com (
   1173351722
   10800
   3600
   432000
   38400 )
  NS ns1.domain.com.
  NS ns2.domain.com.
  A 192.168.1.1
www  A 192.168.1.1
webmail.domain.com IN A 192.168.1.1



this is file domain2.com.hosts   
domain2.com. IN SOA ns1.domain2.com. root.domain2.com (
   1173351722
   10800
   3600
   432000
   38400 )
  NS ns1.domain2.com.
  NS ns2.domain2.com.
  A 192.168.1.1
www  A 192.168.1.1
webmail.domain2.com IN A 192.168.1.1

Comment: Edit the question instead, comments have insufficient formatting capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `xx.com.hosts` should have `webmail.xx.com` added,

```
for f in *.com.hosts; do
    echo "${f%hosts} IN A 192.168.1.1" >>"$f"
done
```

The construct `${var%suffix}` produces the value of `$var` with `suffix` removed if present. (There is also a corresponding `#prefix` construct.)